# After tabBar setHidden, the controller's view won't stretch full screen

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, hidden, tabbar

In fact, the screen area where the tab bar was before, now is not accessible. If I add something on to that area, it just got cropped.

I tried setFrame to 320x480 but it won't help

please help

Answer (score 0):

The best I can tell, and I have done considerable research, is that you cannot go full screen when you have a tabBar without playing a lot of tricks with the view hierarchy.  Assuming the view hierarchy is dangerous because Apple may change it in a future revision.  In my case I wrote my own tabBar replacement.